# Linq Query Return Error

Tags: linq

I cannot figure out why my return from a linq query always is not correct.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public List<Programs> GetPrograms()
    {
        using (var context = new ProgramsDataContext1())
        {

             var qry = (from a in context.Programs 

                      join b in context.courselist on a.Prog_id equals(b.prog_id)
                      where a.Prog_id ==b.prog_id 
                      orderby a.Programname
                      select new 
                      { Prog_id =a.Prog_id,Programname=a.Programname, programlevel=a.programlevel, planname=a.planname, catalogNo=b.catalogNO, coursetitle=b.coursetitle, subject=b.subject
                      }
                      ).ToList();


            return qry ;
        }

    }
```

It always has a red underline on the qry. What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: How is defined the class Programs? The select doesn't create instance of Programs but anonymous object instances, The final ToList cannot match your return `List<Programs>`

Comment: Programs is a table class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing the join already, you do not need the `where` clause. Also your return type is not the same, that's the error you are getting. You are right now returning a list of `anonymous` objects, not `Programs`

Comment: I am trying to return columns from both programs and courselist tables. How to I return the correct type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user788448, you need to create a new poco/dto to return all the data you need and then send a `List<dto>` back. And in your query you create `new dto{}` in the `select`

Answer (score 0):

Just define a class that lists just the properties you need from the two classes and instead of building an anonymous object create instances of this class.

```
public class ProgramsCourseDto
{
   public int Prog_id {get;set;}
   public string Programname {get;set;}
   public int programlevel {get;set;}
   public string planname {get;set;}
   public int catalogNo {get;set;}
   public string coursetitle {get;set;}
   public string subject {get;set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public List<ProgramsCourseDto> GetProgramsCourses()
{
    using (var context = new ProgramsDataContext1())
    {

         var qry = (from a in context.Programs 
                  join b in context.courselist on a.Prog_id equals(b.prog_id)
                  orderby a.Programname
                  select new ProgramsCourseDto
                  { 
                       Prog_id =a.Prog_id,
                       Programname=a.Programname, 
                       programlevel=a.programlevel, 
                       planname=a.planname, 
                       catalogNo=b.catalogNO, 
                       coursetitle=b.coursetitle, 
                       subject=b.subject
                  }).ToList();
        return qry ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Create a new ProgramsCourseDto class solved my program.